# kafkaconsumerfactory vs kafkalistenercontainerfactory

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

What is the relationship / difference between consumer and container in Spring Kafka?
I'm asking this question because Spring provides kafkaconsumerfactory and  kafkalistenercontainerfactory and I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

They work together. You're not required to use `@KafkaListener` annotated methods, but if you do, you'll need to configure both as the listener container needs a configured consumer.

Otherwise, you can use the consumer factory to construct a manual instance of a consumer object

Comment: Thanks for the information. Would you be able to describe the relationship between the two, how they interact?

Comment: The container factory creates the listener container(s) which invoke the listener(s) with records received from their consumer(s). Listener containers need a `ConsumerFactory` to create their consumers when the container is `start()`ed.